# WiFi connection issue

Tags: networking, wireless, connection

I am not able to connect Kubuntu to WiFi . I can only connect with wired connection .Please
tell me how can I connect it to WiFi.I am also not able to find any video on YouTube.

Comment: You didn't provide release details, but most helpful is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide and the *Device Recognition and Operation* links which tells you how to get details as to your chipset providing wifi, and thus the clue on getting it to work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.